# Custom csv import and merge function for multiple files in r

Tags: r, csv

I have over 100 csv files that contain data like this...

```
> dput(head(hobo.temp))
structure(list(Serial = c("ï»¿Plot Title: 20461693", "#", "1", 
"2", "3", "4"), Date = c("", "Date Time, GMT-05:00", "02/14/20 10:14:50 AM", 
"02/14/20 10:14:57 AM", "02/14/20 11:14:50 AM", "02/14/20 12:14:50 PM"
), Temp = c("", "Temp, Â°C (LGR S/N: 20461693, SEN S/N: 20461693)", 
"18.866", "", "20.817", "20.913"), X1 = c("", "Coupler Detached (LGR S/N: 20461693, SEN S/N: 20461693)", 
"", "Logged", "", ""), X2 = c("", "Coupler Attached (LGR S/N: 20461693, SEN S/N: 20461693)", 
"", "", "", ""), X3 = c("", "Host Connected (LGR S/N: 20461693, SEN S/N: 20461693)", 
"", "", "", ""), X4 = c("", "End Of File (LGR S/N: 20461693, SEN S/N: 20461693)", 
"", "", "", "")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

It's nasty so I wrote code to clean it up...

```
hobo.temp <- read.csv("20461693_suw_main_01_19_2021.csv",
                      colClasses = c(rep("character", 3), rep("NULL", 4)),
                      col.names = c("Serial", "Date", "Temp", 1, 2, 3, 4), 
                      header = FALSE, fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
hobo.temp$Date = as.POSIXct(hobo.temp$Date,  format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
hobo.temp[,1] <- hobo.temp[1,1]
hobo.temp <- hobo.temp[-c(1:4),]
hobo.temp <- na.omit(hobo.temp)
hobo.temp <- arrange(hobo.temp, Date)
row.names(hobo.temp) <- NULL
hobo.temp$Serial <- gsub("ï»¿Plot Title: ", "", hobo.temp$Serial, fixed = TRUE)
hobo.temp$Temp <- as.numeric(hobo.temp$Temp)
return(hobo.temp)
```

But when I tried to convert it to a function and iterate it using this code.

```
filenames <- list.files(path = ".", pattern='^.*\\.csv$')

hobo.read <- function(fnam) {
  hobo.temp <- read.csv(fnam, colClasses = c(rep("character", 3), rep("NULL", 4)),
                        col.names = c("Serial", "Date", "Temp", 1, 2, 3, 4), 
                        header = FALSE, fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  hobo.temp$Date = as.POSIXct(hobo.temp$Date,  format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
  hobo.temp[,1] <- hobo.temp[1,1]
  hobo.temp <- hobo.temp[-c(1:4),]
  hobo.temp <- na.omit(hobo.temp)
  hobo.temp <- arrange(hobo.temp, Date)
  row.names(hobo.temp) <- NULL
  hobo.temp$Serial <- gsub("ï»¿Plot Title: ", "", hobo.temp$Serial, fixed = TRUE)
  hobo.temp$Temp <- as.numeric(hobo.temp$Temp)
  return(hobo.temp)
}

my.df <- do.call("rbind", lapply(filenames, hobo.read))
```

I get this error

```
 Error in read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  : 
  more columns than column names
```

I'm terrible at writing functions so I apologize in advance.

Comment: May be some of the files have an issue because you are specifying the `colClasses` assuming that there will be 7 columns.

Comment: Concur with @akrun. This indicates not as much a problem with your function as with at least one of the data files. The problem might be in the 5th or 95th file, no way to know until you edit them all. For debugging, I suggest you add a `message(fnam)` before the `read.csv` so that you'll get context of *which* file is problematic, and can focus your attention on that one file. (Off the cuff, it suggests that whatever made those files did not adhere to the CSV standard. Or perhaps one or more files have other than 7 columns. Idk.)

Comment: I only want the first 3 columns, but colClasses was the only way i could figure it out. This was in an attempt to standardize the number of columns in case the exact scenario you both mentioned is indeed occurring. I tried adding message(nam) but it didn't work.

Comment: If `message(nam)` (sic, `fnam`?) didn't work, then you have a much different problem. How did it not work? It wasn't meant to fix *anything*, it was meant solely so that when you get the error, you know exactly what file caused the error. From there, you can open the file elsewhere and figure out what is broken about it. Or you can run your code manually and test other things. Or you can go back to the source of the data and find out what they think about the problem. Or many things. Regardless, *"it didn't work"* is not helpful.

Comment: I don't know how to insert it into my code. It's okay I found the problem. you guys were right, a handful of files had 8 columns and i didn't realize my ``c(rep("character", 3), rep("NULL", 4)``` code wasn't covering the 8th column. I switched the 4 to a 5 and its working perfectly now.

Comment: I'm still curious as to how you would insert ```messages(nam)``` into
```hobo.read <- function(x) {
  df1 <- read.csv(x, colClasses = c(rep("character", 3), rep("NULL", 5)),
                        col.names = c("Serial", "Date", "Temp", 1, 2, 3, 4), 
                        header = FALSE, fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  df2 <- hobo.fix(df1)
  
} ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that a few of the files had 8 columns. I thought this might be the case and was trying to account for it with my original question code `colClasses = c(rep("character", 3), rep("NULL", 4))` When I switched the 4 to a 5 in ```rep("NULL", 5)), it correctly nullified that 8th column. I modified my original question code to be slightly more readable (maybe). This is my first real function, and it's nested to boot. It's sloppy but I'm pretty proud of it.

```
    #reads filenames from 
filenames <- list.files(path = ".", pattern='^.*\\.csv$')

#first function imports data
hobo.read <- function(x) {
  #in... rep("NULL", 5)... 5 has to be larger than the number for columns in the csv with the largest number of columns
  df1 <- read.csv(x, colClasses = c(rep("character", 3), rep("NULL", 5)),
                        col.names = c("Serial", "Date", "Temp", 1, 2, 3, 4), 
                        header = FALSE, fill = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  # line applies the action function below
  df2 <- hobo.fix(df1)
  
}

#function of actions to apply within 1st function
hobo.fix <- function(hobo.temp) {
  hobo.temp[,1] <- hobo.temp[1,1]
  hobo.temp <- hobo.temp[-c(1:4),]
  hobo.temp$Serial <- gsub("ï»¿Plot Title: ", "", hobo.temp$Serial, fixed = TRUE)
  hobo.temp$Temp <- as.numeric(hobo.temp$Temp)
  hobo.temp$Date = as.POSIXct(hobo.temp$Date,  format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
  hobo.temp <- na.omit(hobo.temp)
  hobo.temp <- dplyr::arrange(hobo.temp, Date)
  row.names(hobo.temp) <- NULL
  return(hobo.temp)
}


hobo <- do.call("rbind", lapply(filenames, hobo.read))
```